# How do I load a queue with messages from a topic that the queue is bridged to in Tibco EMS?

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, ems

I have a bridge created between Topic A and Queue B.  Topic A has messages on it but Queue B doesn't.  Queue B was created after those messages hit Topic A.  Is there a way to get those messages into the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Topic does not "keep" messages for subscribers like a queue would. Hence your messages don't "exist" anymore.

If you subscribe with a topic, you are going to receive every messages sent to the topic ONLY as long as your session is ongoing.

The only exception is "Durable subscriptions". In that last case, the system create "queues" of messages to be sent to each durable subscriber... and if a session is ended, the pending "Topic" messages will wait for the subscribers.

In your case, since the Queue B existed AFTER the concerned message have hit Topic A... The messages are already "lost" to Queue B, since the bridge (the subscriber, in this case) did not exist at that time.

See link : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/basics.html